# Linux command find usage confuse

Tags: linux, bash, find

Today when I was using the "find" command. It is a little bit confusing on the usage.

The problem: I want to count how many gz files under the main directory. However, the main dir also have sub directories. e.g. /mainDir/Dir1/1/  /mainDir/Dir2/1/2012. Under each sub folder, there are several gz files.

I use command 1, it works fine.

First I go the the main directory:

```
ls -R . | find -name "*.gz" | wc -l
```

However, if I use command 2, it return 0:

```
ls -R /home/user1/data1/2012/mainDir | find -name "*.gz" | wc -l
```

What is the reason, Any one got some idea?

thanks,

Comment: I actually don't understand the purpose of you using ls in the first place.

Comment: The `find` command does not read its standard input; there is no point in piping anything to it.  You also need to supply a directory name (or several names) between the command name `find` and the action arguments such as `-name '*.gz'`.

Comment: You can't pipe names to `find`, it doesn't read its standard input. If you don't give it a starting directory on the command line, it starts from the current dir.

Comment: @Barmar: classically, you have to provide a pathname; BSD `find` still requires it.  It is GNU `find` that interpolates `.` if you miss out any pathname.  Given that the question mentions Linux, that's fair enough.

Comment: I guess a GNU developer noticed that 90% of the time people use `find .`, so he decided to make it the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `ls`. Simply `find . -name '*.gz' | wc -l` or `find /home/user1/data1/2012/mainDir -name '*.gz' | wc -l`. The words in a `find` command before the hyphen options like `-name` are the names of directories in which to search.

Comment: Exactly, the find command does its own file search, traversing sub directories.  `ls` simply list the files in the current directory.

Comment: I use "ls" is because I want to get the full path of each file. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, just don't pipe `find` to `wc` and you'll have the path of each file relative to whatever directory name you provided. That is because the default action of `find` is the same as if you had ended with the option `-print`. There are other options such as `-ls`. You could even use `tee` if you'd like to arrange to get both the paths and the total count in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 find /home/user1/data1/2012/mainDir -name "*.gz" | wc -l
```

This conforms to standard find syntax and does what you want.